# Run-Time Error 1004 when displaying Date/Time

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

The code below is used to recognise when a change occurs on any sheet in the workbook. Then on the sheet where the changes happened, show the date + time in cell `B1` and the user who made the change in `D1`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sh
        If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:D1")) Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:mm:ss")
            ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = Application.UserName
        Else
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

But the code errors when trying to action somehing like copy+paste cells in one sheet or across 2

[image]

Tried looking for solutions and using different syntax (like `wsPOD` instead of `Activesheet`) but either errors with same actions or errors on any change.

Comment: When you copy from one sheet and try to paste to an array of sheets then the `Target` and the `Range("A1:D1")` refer to different sheets. You can check that by putting a break point and then checking `?Target.Parent.Name` and similarly `?Range("A1:D1").Parent.Name` and you will see that they are different and hence the error. You can get rid of that by fully qualifying the range object. For example, `If Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A1:D1")) Is Nothing Then`. You will not get an error now.

Comment: Similarly replace `ActiveSheet` with `Sh` in the other two lines. Or rather simply delete `ActiveSheet` and let `.Range("B1").Value` remain so that `With sh` qualifies it.

Answer (score 3):

### A Workbook Sheet Change: Time Stamp And User

- If you don't disable events, then the event will trigger each time you write to the cell again and again resulting in an endless loop, probably crashing Excel.
- Also, you should have used:

  ```
  If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("A1:D1")) Is Nothing Then
  ```

  focus on `Not`, and the dot in front of `Range` i.e. `.Range`.
  The following code uses the opposite to exit the procedure.

**The Code**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Restrict to a range e.g. 'A1:D1'
    If Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A1:D1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Out-comment the above line to use for a change in any cell.
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' to not retrigger the event
        Sh.Range("B1").Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:mm:ss")
        Sh.Range("D1").Value = Application.UserName
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: nicely done. Also since you are working with `EnableEvents `, you may want to introduce proper error handling? I have spoken about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure)